# Firebase Database & AngularJS - Results on load after button click/action

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, scope, firebase-realtime-database

I'm able to retrieve data from my Firebase database, but my scopes aren't updating until after I click a button or input field on the page. I'm assuming it's something with AngularJS, but I can't figure it out.

Here's my function to read the data from Firebase:

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  database.ref('/users/' + userId).on('value', function(snapshot) {

    console.log(snapshot.val().user);
    console.log(snapshot.val().weight);
    console.log(snapshot.val().updated);

    $scope.displayName = snapshot.val().user;
  });
```

The `console.log` results are fine and the `scope.displayName` is fine, but the scope itself won't update until after I click a button and I want it to update on page load(as soon as the `database.ref` runs).

The binding:

```
<p>{{displayName}}</p>
```

Comment: It's because the scope is inside of the .on() function. It's looking for a change in the value before it alters the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Create a two way binding to  "displayName" in your HTML code. That way it will show the initial value and change as the value changes.

What does you HTML look like?

Comment: It's already binded using <p>{{displayName}}</p> but still only displays any value after a button click.

Comment: You need to set the displayName based off the firebase id in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using $scope.apply.